# Export and format Data from Azure Repository

Tags: azure, export, kql

I want to insert a data column from a Table in an Azure Repo to automate checking for IOCs

This is the current query:

```
DeviceNetworkEvent
| where Timestamp > ago(30d)
| where RemoteIP in ~(HERE)
```

I would copy the data from the currently used Excel-Sheet to Notepad++ and format it to look like this:

```
"DataPoint1",
"DataPoint2",
"DataPoint3"
```

which i would then Copy into the query instead of HERE.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a table to create a place to easily copy your data from excel:

```
let table = datatable(column:string)
[
   "DataPoint1",
   "DataPoint2"
];
DeviceNetworkEvent
| where Timestamp > ago(30d)
| where RemoteIP in (table)
```

Another way, if you want to automate this, is to write the data to a storage account and query that data using the [externaldata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/externaldata-operator?pivots=azuremonitor) operator:

```
let table = externaldata(column:string)
[
  h@"https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxx/data.txt?sv=2019-10-10&st=2020-09-29T11%3A39%3A22Z&se=2050-09-30T11%3A39%3A00Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=%2BuIzJYJzkvLZpp03e0SvTD3pbcK%2BVBHl4Z58Coj8hys%3D"
]
with(format="csv");
DeviceNetworkEvent
| where Timestamp > ago(30d)
| where RemoteIP in (table)
```

Comment: Sorry for being late but when i try this i get:
'where' operator: Failed to resolve table or column or scalar expression named 'IOC'
`let IOC = externaldata(column:string)
[
  h@"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kornuptiko/TEMP/main/KQL_Test_Data.csv"
]
with(format="csv");

DeviceNetworkEvents
| where Timestamp > ago(30d)
| where RemoteIP in (IOC)`